# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.forgottenitem.myevent1. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: android

I am new to android. Kindly assist me with this error message:

```
2021-07-03 14:07:51.800 5006-5006/com.real.myevent1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-07-03 14:07:51.803 5006-5006/com.real.myevent1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.real.myevent1/com.real.myevent1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.forgottenitem.myevent1. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.forgottenitem.myevent1. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:184)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.1:1)
    at com.real.myevent1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 


2021-07-03 14:52:35.108 5997-5997/com.real.myevent1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.real.myevent1, PID: 5997
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.real.myevent1/com.real.myevent1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.real.myevent1. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.real.myevent1. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:184)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.1:1)
        at com.real.myevent1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2021-07-03 14:52:35.218 5997-5997/com.real.myevent1 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5997 SIG: 9
```

Comment: This is my Main Activity

Comment: Add this FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) to your MainActivity  onCreate() function

Comment: Thanks, Noban. I just did. However, it still came with the same error

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is not initialized so init firebase before any firebase access. Better place to add is in application class.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
```